# How to decide which BI tool is suitable in a particular scenario, SSAS or OBIEE?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse

For a large Data Base which one is better in performance. which one will give data very fast on MDX query execution.

Comment: Hello Jeevan Bhatt. I'm voting to close your question as "Not a real question", which is "incomplete, overly broad [...] and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form" - it cannot really be answered beyond *it depends* - on your hardware, uses, table structure, data types, indices, etc etc...

Comment: Hello Kobi, My question has no dependency over hardware, uses table structure and data type, i have a 200 GB data in form of csv file which contain very basic data type like integer and decimal, Now i have to decide which one will be better for Business Analysis, suppose we need to chose any one of them. So my question is real question, got it.

Comment: Excellent, I got it! Then you should expand the question and explain exactly what you have and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually data is related to Banking domain like customer, account and transaction details so i want to use BI so that client can do any type of cross tab between them.

Comment: A good design is as important or more important than a good tool.  You could have the best tool in the universe but a rubbish schema and the tool won't make the difference.  It's not possible to say which tool would perform better without talking about your schema design.

Comment: @Sir Wobin: You are right but consider my scenario as describe above when u went through it then i hope u will understand my requirement. now if you have to chose or if client want to ask this question to you than what will be your answer ?  and what tool will you use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a 200GB data set, SSAS on an ordinary wintel server will be fine.  It plays nicely with readily available front-end tools and will be much, much cheaper than Oracle unless you already have incumbent OBIEE licencing.

Comment: Thanks ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells atleast you gave response of this question, hmm...you said, till 200GB data SSAA is ok but if i have no issue with price of licensing and learning curve of both tool SSAA and OBIEE then which tool should i use ?

Comment: OBIEE is what used to be Siebel Analytics when Oracle bought Siebel.  Siebel was a bit of a niche player in that space - SSAS has a pretty good feature set since SQL Server 2005.  In most cases you're probably best off with SSAS unless you need a siebel-specific feature.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i search on net but could not find exactly what is siebel-specific feature, so could u please tell me some difference between both features.